# Append Camera Image in ListBox in ANdroid

Tags: android, android-listview

In my code after pressing camera button `onActivityResult` called(as a result of an intent). In this method I have written code to add captured image in `listView`. All I want is that when I capture image second time, then first image in `listView` should not vanish. If I have captured image three times, then there should be three `listview` items. My code shows only one item each time I capture image. I have tried a lot and can't figure it out. 
Thanks.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> hashMapListForListView=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();     

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {



        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK )
        {      
  if (requestCode == take_image) {

        //get image
              final Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");  

            Viewimage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

              Adapter=new SimpleAdapter(this,hashMapListForListView,R.layout.imageview2,new String[]{"image"}, new int[]{R.id.imageView2});


            HashMap<String, Object>temp11=new HashMap<String, Object>();
            //Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),thumbnail);
            temp11.put("image",thumbnail);

            hashMapListForListView.add(temp11);
            listviewattachment.setAdapter(Adapter);
            Adapter.setViewBinder(new MyViewBinder());
            Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening just because you are creating adapter every time in `onActivityResult()`. Second thing is, no need to set adapter again and again by using `setAdapter()` but `notifyDataSetChanged()` is required only.

**Update:**

As you said in comment, you want to remove item from list, try:

```
Object toRemove = arrayAdapter.getItem([POSITION]);
arrayAdapter.remove(toRemove);
```

Comment: thanks Paresh ..it's working..can you tell how can i remove any item i don't like in list ??